# Is it proper to compare a full linear mixed effect model that converges and an refined model that does not?

Tags: mixed-model

I was trying to construct in Rstudio a full LME model and a refined one (full model minus one predictor) and using anova() to get the main effect of the dropped predictor. My full model converged (but with singular fit) while the refined model could not converge. So my question is whether it is still proper to compare the two models. If not, what should I do? Should I simplify the random model?

Answer (score 2):

If the models have not converged, it is not a good idea to compare them. A singular fit is also a problematic situation. You could try other optimization algorithms, e.g., fitting with `lme()` of package **nlme** instead of `lmer()` of **lme4** or to simplify your model.